# SQL Query to generate an output table

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, plsql, dynamic-list

I have two tables, One is employee registration where the data is provided of the employees (Name, ID, Phone, State etc)  and the other is the Data Collected by Employees or Prospects Table (Whenever, he goes to collect data in field consisting information about the individuals he visits).

Now, the task is to output the table-
[image: Desired Output Table]

Here is the desired table, I want to get from my Query.

Where CG-DL-GJ etc. are the different states.

Now, I am able to get the Data overall Collected by mapping the two tables and getting the sum of the prospect table by using employee ID in both the tables for mapping.

I am using the following Query to get the same,

```
select
    sum(case when r.state = 'CG' then 1 else 0 end) as "CG",
    sum(case when r.state = 'DL' then 1 else 0 end) as "DL",
    sum(case when r.state = 'GJ' then 1 else 0 end) as "GJ",
    sum(case when r.state = 'MH' then 1 else 0 end) as "MH",
    sum(case when r.state = 'MP' then 1 else 0 end) as "MP",
    sum(case when r.state = 'PJB' then 1 else 0 end) as "PJB",
    sum(case when r.state = 'RAJ' then 1 else 0 end) as "RAJ",
    sum(case when r.state = 'HR' then 1 else 0 end) as "HR",
    sum(case when r.state in ('RAJ', 'PJB', 'MP' , 'MH', 'GJ', 'DL', 'CG', 'HR') then 1 else 0 end) as "Grand Total"
    from
    _au_all_prospects p,
    _au_all_registrations r
    where p.employee_id = r.employee_id
```

I am getting this output:

```
CG  DL  GJ  MH  MP  PJB RAJ HR  Grand Total
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   24  25
```

but dont know, how to do the aggregation such as category defined in the output table like % of Data Collected in 0-30%, 30-50%, 50-100%, >100% etc. For each Employee, the threshold data points he needs to collect is 10 points per day. So, if he does 60 points collections per week, it will be 100% for him.

I need to build a similar table not an exact one, I need suggestions, above is my query, which i need to change, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really sure what's the requirement, but - can't you just wrap this query in another one, which will divide for instance "CG" column to the "Grand Total" and see what's the ratio (this will give you a percentage of the total). something like `select "CG"/"Grant Total" as CG_Perc
     , ...
     , "Grant Total"
from ( your_query );` ?

Comment: yes, it seems a nice idea, but this is not what I need to get.

Comment: 70 points per week? Your report only shows periods of 5 days though.

Comment: Thanks I have changed it.